# Project output type not changing to console application, Console window not showing in WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core

I am working on a Windows Forms on .NET Core project and was needing to display the console window and to print some information using `Console.WriteLine()`.
I usually have been doing this in winform projects by changing the output type to "Console Application" in the project property Through `Project >> [my project name] Properties` But It's currently changing back to "Windows Application" after I save it and open the setting back.

Why is this happening? how can I solve this?

I also tried deleting `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` from the project file, and that makes the problem even worse.

Comment: Why print to console? Why not use logger

Comment: @ilansch the output window doesn't show what I write by `Console.WriteLine`, or is it another window?

Comment: You need to be more clear, Output window is used during debug in visual studio. Console will be used on runtime. I meant, if yoy neex output to be printed, the proper way is logging to a file with log4net or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to force show the console window using this code,

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Added this call
    AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Comment: That will work, just note that you'll always get a new console, even if your process was started from an existing console.

Comment: @Abraham, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 soulutions:

1. Change in your main method of `Program.cs`: Remove lines of code related to Forms. Change it by `Console.WriteLine("bar");`
2. You still print information to console along side with Windows Forms.
   just put `Console.WriteLine("foo");` or something else to main method of `Program.cs` .

Comment: But the problem is that It doesn't display the console window at all.

Comment: You can see in Visual Studio's output tab.

Comment: It's flooded with irrelevant data like thread quiting, compile information... I can't see my log clearly there, like in the console window